# Can't trigger SelectedIndexChanged event for a dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, drop-down-menu

I'm a beginner in C# and asp.net, i have a DropDownList with an item with text : `"No item selected."` and index `0`.

I have a button `Delete` which obviously, deletes items from the DDL.

But i want to disable it when there's only the `"No item selected."` item.

I tried this code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button2.Enabled = false;
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        Button2.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Button2.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

But nothing happens when i add new items and select it. The `Delete` button is still disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!Page.IsPosBack)
  {
    Button2.Enabled = false;
  }
}
```

It was resetting to "disabled" after postback

Answer (score 1):

You have to check your drop down list AutoPostBack Property it must true to fire a server side event and also at the time of page_load event check with IsPostBack property then try.